# Чи можна використовувати слово "кЕшеня"?

Tags: іменники, правопис, орфографія

У [словнику за редакцією Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F) подається така стаття:

> **Кешеня**, ні, ж. = **Кишеня**.

Виходячи з цього, слово таки можна вживати. Однак, на скільки я знаю, це суперечить нормам правопису.

Отже, чи справді можна використовувати слово "***кЕшеня***"? Чи, можливо, у словнику за ред. Б. Грінченка таки помилка? Адже у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kyshenja) зафіксовано ЛИШЕ "***кИшеня***".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, це суперечить [нормам правипу](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par2p1) і дуже схоже до [вашого минулого](/q/4417/) запитання з **а**—**у**:

> #### § 2. Ненаголошені *Е*, *И*
>
> 1. У складах із ненаголошеними **е** та **и** пишеться та сама літера, що й під наголосом: *вели́кий*, *величе́зний* (бо *ве́лич*), *держу́* (бо *оде́ржати*), *клекоті́ти* (бо *кле́кіт*), *несу́* (бо *прине́сений*), *шепоті́ти* (бо *ше́піт*), *криве́* (бо *кри́во*), *трима́ти* (бо *отри́мувати*), *широ́кий* (бо *ши́роко*).
>
>    У словах із постійним наголосом невиразний звук рекомендується перевіряти за словниками: *лева́да*, *лемі́ш*, ***кише́ня***, *мину́лий*.

Тому чинною літературною можна лиш **кишення**.

Словник Грінченка поважний, але не слїд забувати, що:

- базував ся на 1907—1909 (в статтях навіть можна зустріти **ѣ**), тому частенько він є джерелом для порівнянь чи існуванню декотрих слів (тієї ж *кешеня*); навіть частенько вживаний тут [СУМ-11](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) теж можна [вважати старим](/q/4429/585), оскільки писав ся під час совітського поневолення і минулого столїття — нове привнесло багато анґліцізмів, але залишає ся поважним через наповнення і незавершення новішого [СУМ-20](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) (сьогоденний має поки 8 книг і включає слова лиш до [*мішуриний*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/)); як би дурно не звучало, останній теж може вважати трохи застарим, оскільки, по-моєму, він базує ся на старій книжній схемі складання, коли наразї переважно все створюють за допомогою і для компʼютерів, також і наразї мова розвиває ся, але від цього менш поважнішим не стає, також підсилює ся як найʼостанній вагомий представник;
- основні слова зазвичай мають повноцїнну статтю, а побічні відсилають до основної, тобто стаття *кешеня* відсилає до *кишеня*, отже друге є основним.

Як знаємо і бачимо, правопис — це лиш норми для літературної та дїлової мови, тому можна не завше слїдувати і текти за лоґікою. Цьому наприклад допоможе [етимолоґічний словник](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=440):

> **кише́ня**, [*кеше́ня*], *кишенько́вий*;
>
> р. [*кише́нь*] «кишеня», [*кише́ня*] «тс.; черево;», бр. *кішэ́нь* «кишеня», *кішэ́ня*,п. kieszeń, ч. [kešeňa], слн. [kešeň, kešeňa, kišeňa] «тс.»;
>
> псл. *kyšenja, можливо, «гаман з кишки», утворено, мабуть, від kyšьka «кишка»;
>
> варіант *кеше́ня* виник вторинно внаслідок дистантної асиміляції голосних;
>
> п. kieszenia могло постати внаслідок схрещення рефлексів псл. *kyšenja і *kъsenь «шлунок, нутрощі» (збереженого в п. ст. ksieniec «тс.» і полаб. tʼėsin «шлунок»);
>
> те саме, можливо, стосується чеських та словацьких слів;
>
> думка (Mikl. TEI 2, 109; Macheck ESJČ 249) про звʼязок слова з тюркізмом *киса́* «мішечок» не доведена.
>
> Дзендзелівський УЗЛП 72—73; [Фасмер 2 242](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&text_word=%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&method_word=substring); Sławski 2 158—159; Brückner 278; Bańkowski JP 61, 44; Bern. 1 503.
>
> Див. ще [ки́шка](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=441).

Де:

- значна частина поважних словників взазують на спорідненість з словом *ки́шка*, де **и** наголошене — **е** неможливе;
- вказують на *кешеня* як вторинне (*від с.*: також можливий додатковий вплив сусїдних мов, але для цього треʼ перевірити місця розповсюдження поширення слова *кешеня*);

Не маю підстав не довіряти, особливо наросток *еня* не змінює корінь слова. Тому лоґіка не порушена, а отже вжив *кишеня* вагоміший, чого не написати про *кешеня*.